# CMake with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, cmake

I'm using CMake to create a visual studio project as I'm making a cross platform application and library, but I get errors like:

> 1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\wchar.h(109): warning C4820: '_wfinddata64i32_t' : '4' bytes padding added after data member '_wfinddata64i32_t::attrib'

It compiles fine on GNU/Linux using gcc and I haven't tried MinGW. Yet.

Comment: off course it compiles fine on linux: it doesn't have the same wchar.h header

Comment: I know it doesn't, but I'm not using any linux-specific code or even wchar knowingly.

Comment: Could you give the complete errors?

Comment: Sure, http://pastebin.com/AMG2KN5D .

Comment: Turns out this was due to having ALL warnings on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the opengl errors, you need to include `windows.h` before including `gl.h`. Hope it helps.

```
#ifdef WIN32
# include <windows.h>
#endif
#include <GL/gl.h>
```

Comment: Thanks but luckily I still get to enjoy a wide range of padding warnings and every other error Visual Studio can give me.